# Printing out results inside 2 whiles

Tags: php, html

So im building a fast food website i have built most of it apart from displaying the menu this will be different for each take away which is signed up. I have worked out that im gonna have categories and items so the take away can have a categories called "trays" then  5 items inside that categories with all the different trays they do then they can make another categorie for another block of food and so on. Problem i have is i will need to print out the categories and the items. I have 1 table called categories then another called topics the items will be stored in the topic table and categories in categories so would need to display it like so

categorie
topic
topic 
topic

over and over.

Here is my html

```html
     <div class="menu-widget" id="2">
                            <div class="widget-heading">
                                <h3 class="widget-title text-dark">
                              POPULAR ORDERS Delicious hot food!      
<a class="btn btn-link pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#popular2" aria-expanded="true">
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                              </a>
                           </h3>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse in" id="popular2">
                                <div class="food-item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                                            <div class="rest-logo pull-left">
                                                <a class="restaurant-logo pull-left" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x80" alt="Food logo"></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end:Logo -->
                                            
                                              <?php echo "food inside";?>
                                            <div class="rest-descr">
                                                <h6><a href="#">Veg Extravaganza</a></h6>
                                                <p> Burgers, American, Sandwiches, Fast Food, BBQ</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end:Description -->
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end:col -->
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 pull-right item-cart-info"> <span class="price pull-left">$ 19.99</span> <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn btn-secondary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#order-modal">&#43;</a> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end:row -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- end:Food item --><!-- end:Food item --><!-- end:Food item -->
                                <div class="food-item white"><!-- end:row -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- end:Food item -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- end:Collapse -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end:Widget menu -->
```

and here is my code

```
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6"><!-- end:Widget menu -->




    <?php

    ///first select the category based on $_GET['cat_id']
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM categories WHERE takeawayid  =' ".$id1."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);




if(!$result)
{
    echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.' . mysql_error();
}
else
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo 'This category does not exist.';
    }
    else
    {
        //display category data
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        ?>


                        <div class="menu-widget" id="2">
                            <div class="widget-heading">
                                <h3 class="widget-title text-dark">
                            <?php  echo $row['cat_name'] ;  ?> <a class="btn btn-link pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#popular2" aria-expanded="true">
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                              </a>
                           </h3>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>






        <?php
                //do a query for the topics

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_cat  =' ".$row['cat_id']."'";




$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
        }



echo $row2['topic_subject'] ;

        if(!$result2)
        {
            echo 'The topics could not be displayed, please try again later.';
        }
        else
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0)
            {
                echo 'There are no topics in this category yet.';
            }
            else
            {
                //prepare the table
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                {   


                    ?>






                            <div class="collapse in" id="popular2">
                                <div class="food-item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                                            <div class="rest-logo pull-left">
                                                <a class="restaurant-logo pull-left" href="#"><img src="http://sdfsdf.com/beta/restaurants/<?php echo $id33  ;?>.png" alt="Food logo"></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end:Logo -->


                                            <div class="rest-descr">
                                                <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $row2['topic_subject'] ;?></a></h6>
                                                <p> Burgers, American, Sandwiches, Fast Food, BBQ</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end:Description -->
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end:col -->
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 pull-right item-cart-info"> <span class="price pull-left">$ 19.99</span> <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn btn-secondary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#order-modal">&#43;</a> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end:row -->


                                </div>
                                <!-- end:Food item --><!-- end:Food item --><!-- end:Food item -->
                                <div class="food-item white"><!-- end:row -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- end:Food item -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- end:Collapse -->


                 </div>
                 </div>

                                    <?php

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>





                        <!-- end:Widget menu -->
```

Code works but when i add more than 1 result im getting this
http://prntscr.com/fu3qll

Here is 1 cat and 2 topics in side it
https://prnt.sc/fu3g2j

works great but when i add 2 cats and 4 topics 2 inside each one i get above the fu3kbk link

Comment: Please read about Separation of Concerns

Answer (score 0):

so i fixed it by moving the bracket down on
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

```
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6"><!-- end:Widget menu -->





    <?php

    ///first select the category based on $_GET['cat_id']
$sql = "SELECT    * FROM categories WHERE takeawayid  =' ".$id1."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);




if(!$result)
{
    echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.' . mysql_error();
}
else
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo 'This category does not exist.';
    }
    else
    {
        //display category data
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        ?>


                        <div class="menu-widget" id="2">
                            <div class="widget-heading">
                                <h3 class="widget-title text-dark">
                            <?php  echo $row['cat_name'] ;  ?> <a class="btn btn-link pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#popular2" aria-expanded="true">
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                              </a>
                           </h3>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>




        <?php
                //do a query for the topics








            $sql2 = "SELECT    * FROM topics WHERE topic_cat  =' ".$row['cat_id']."'";       
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);


        if(!$result2)
        {
            echo 'The topics could not be displayed, please try again later.';
        }
        else
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0)
            {
                echo 'There are no topics in this category yet.';
            }
            else
            {
                //prepare the table
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                {    


                    ?>






                            <div class="collapse in" id="popular2">
                                <div class="food-item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                                            <div class="rest-logo pull-left">
                                                <a class="restaurant-logo pull-left" href="#"><img src="http://geatzo.com/beta/restaurants/<?php echo $id33  ;?>.png" alt="Food logo"></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end:Logo -->


                                            <div class="rest-descr">
                                                <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $row2['topic_subject'] ;?></a></h6>
                                                <p> Burgers, American, Sandwiches, Fast Food, BBQ</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end:Description -->
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end:col -->
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 pull-right item-cart-info"> <span class="price pull-left">$ 0</span> <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn btn-secondary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#order-modal">+</a> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end:row -->


                                </div>
                                <!-- end:Food item --><!-- end:Food item --><!-- end:Food item -->

                                <!-- end:Food item -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- end:Collapse -->


                                    <?php

                }
            }
        }
    }
     }
}
?>



                            </div>

                            </div>
                        <!-- end:Widget menu -->
```